# UI to invite multiple users with specific roles and permissions

Tags: website-design, gui-design, ux-designer, webforms

I have an application where I am sending invitations to multiple users at a time. The current UI is very simple, but now requirement has changed: invite users with various roles and permissions.

I have created the following design:
[image]

Here is the explanation of the design:

1. List of textboxes to add emails for inviting new users.
2. Roles and permissions: We can invite user with certain roles and permissions by selecting roles checkbox.
3. Group, Division, and Team Drop-downs are there for inviting users in specific team.
4. Top most checkbox: If we want to invite lets say 100 users with same roles and permission as first user we can check this checkbox. If this checkbox is selected, following screen variant is visible:

[image]

For such bulk invitations, this screen variant looks confusing, and there is too much white space.

How can we improve this bulk-invite design to make this screen more user friendly and efficient?

Comment: Hi Swapnali, this question reads a bit like "please design my interface for me". Questions along the lines of "looking for better UX" are generally off topic because they either fall under the category of "site review" or they are just too broad. You say that you are not satisfied with the design. YIn that case, you need to _focus on a specific aspect of the design that represents an actual or perceived UI/UX problem_ and make your question about that problem.

Comment: Hi Dennislees, as you said I have modified my question.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFXb5p.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

As per your comments, if you require "tighter" UI, you can use a table and display all records at the same time.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f651zF.png)</sup>

Comment: the design given by you is good if i want to set permissions in bulk to invite users. But if I want to give different roles and permissions to every individual, then it is not user friendly. To see the allocated role, permissions, group,division and team, I always needs to open accordion. I can have 5 slots at a time or 20 slots at a time to invite users. If number of slot is big and i want to give separate roles and Group, division, team this will be bit confusing to user.

Comment: @SwapnaliHadawale, I have modified my answer with a second solution.